# How to diff very large buckets in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a use case where I have to back up a 200+TB, 18M object S3 bucket to another account that changes often (used in batch processing of critical data). I need to add a verification step, but due to the large size of both bucket, object count, and frequency of change this is tricky.

My current thoughts are to pull the eTags from the original bucket and archive bucket, and the write a streaming diff tool to compare the values. Has anyone here had to approach this problem and if so did you come up with a better answer?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you wish to keep two buckets in sync (once you've done the initial sync), you can use [Cross-Region Replication (CRR)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html).

To do the initial sync, you could try using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has a `aws s3 sync` command. However, it might have some difficulties with a large number of files -- I suggest you give it a try. It uses keys, dates and filesize to determine which files to sync.

If you do wish to create your own sync app, then **eTag** is definitely a definitive way to compare files.

To make things simple, activate [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily listing of all files in a bucket, including eTag. You could then do a comparison between the Inventory files to discover which remaining files require synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for the response John. We played with both CRR to another account, and s3 sync, but found both to be too slow. We are using a project called s3s3mirror (https://github.com/cobbzilla/s3s3mirror) and found that to be fast enough. I will take a look at S3 Inventory and see if it gives me a better way to generate the eTag manifests. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a way to solve this problem in an automated way (as was I), 
I created a small python script that leverages S3 Inventories and Athena to do the comparison somewhat efficiently. (This is basically automation of John Rosenstein's  suggestion)

You can find it here https://github.com/forter/s3-compare